# __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python

I just started learning Python today, so I am sorry if this is an easy question. I have spent the last half an hour attempting to rectify the following code.

```
class Area:

    def __init__(self,width,height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def rectangle_area(self):
        area = self.width * self.height
        return area

area = Area(200, 100)
print area.rectangle_area()
area = Area(250, 150)
print area.rectangle_area()
```

Every time I run it, I get outputs 20000 and 37500, which is fine, but then I get:

```
'__init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)'
```

Exact output:

```
20000
37500
=> None
'__init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)'
```

Can anyone see the error in this code?

**EDIT:** This is from problem 3 of http://www.learnstreet.com/assignments/525231f376b99c634f000021/practice/5215e57f76b99c0f52000095

**EDIT 2:** The question (Copy paste):

3 : Function **init**
Create a class Area which has a constructor that will assign height as 100 and width as 200. Define a method rectangle_area which should return the area of a rectangle and an instance of Area as area. Print the area of the rectangle. Add 50 to height, and 50 to the width of the area instance. Then print the area of the rectangle.

**EDIT 3:** Making them optional gives:

```
20000
37500
=> None
'Have you created two instances named area.height and area.width?'
```

Comment: You're not showing us all the code.

Comment: That doesn't look like exact output to me. If there is an exception, please post the full traceback.

Comment: I dint find any error!

Comment: I agree with the previous posting, something must come after the last line to spawn the "=> None" output

Comment: @StoryTeller that is all the code I have. I am doing this online (We have to) at http://www.learnstreet.com/assignments/525231f376b99c634f000021/practice/5215e57f76b99c0f52000095 its the 2nd or 3rd one...

Comment: You have two print statements and three lines plus an error in the output. Your exact code as posted works on my machine.

Comment: what happens if you copy and past the text you have posted into a new file and re-run this?

Comment: @Asryael That website requires registration; can you post the code somewhere else please?

Comment: Probably the online grader is trying to create an `Area` without passing width and height as parameters. Did you read the instructions carefully?

Comment: @poke That is the full code. Its running in a jQuery python interpreter (Or something similar)

Comment: Or better yet, post only the relevant lines *here*

Comment: @StoryTeller That is the full code that I am able to view

Comment: Access denied. Please post all your code here.

Comment: What happens if you make width and height optional? `def __init__(self,width=200,height=100):`

Comment: @tobias_k I have edited the response given with them optional.

Comment: Voted to close as "unclear". The code shown is OK and it's a homework (assignment) question which actually offtopic. What a mess.

Comment: @try-catch-finally this actually wasn't a homework question, this was me learning on my own. Not sure how this question is unclear.

Comment: It's unclear in the way that you provide code that *runs* and *does not throw* the exception you show.

Comment: The code was executed within a hidden context on the server, that is all the code I had available to me. Either way, this question is 4 years old now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Function `__init__`: Create a class `Area` which has a constructor that will assign `height` as 100 and `width` as 200. Define a method `rectangle_area` which should return the area of a rectangle and an instance of Area as area. Print the area of the rectangle. Add 50 to `height`, and 50 to the `width` of the area instance. Then print the area of the rectangle.

To me this sounds like this, as useless as that may seem:

```
class Area:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.width = 200
        self.height = 100
    def rectangle_area (self):
        return self.width * self.height

x = Area()
print(x.rectangle_area())
x.width += 50
x.height += 50
print(x.rectangle_area())
```

Comment: This works. Thank you. I found the question a bit ambiguous obviously.

Comment: It definitely is. And it does not really make sense to define a type with a fixed default size. Also to me, an “area” usually connotates an immutable thing.